# Continuous ground truth in supervised (metric) learning?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

I am writing my thesis in the field of (deep) metric learning (DML). I am training a network in the fashion of contrastive / triplet Siamese networks to learn similarity and dissimilarity of inputs. In this context, the ground truth is commonly expressed as a binary. Let's take an example based on the similarity of [species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_wolf#Taxonomy_and_evolution):

- Image A: german shepard (dog)
- Image B: siberian husky (dog)
- Image C: turkish angora (cat)
- Image D: gray wolf (wolf)

> Image A and B are similar: same species, same sub-species (canis lupus) -> **1.0** == `TRUE`
>
> Image A and C are dissimilar: different species (canis lupus vs. felis silvestris) -> **0.0** == `FALSE`
>
> Image A and D ? same species, but different sub-species -> **0.8**

**Which metric learning approaches use a continuous ground truth for learning?**

I could imagine that there is a lot of research out there using a continuous ground truth in classification settings. For instance to learn that the expression of a face is "almost (60%) happy", or more controversial, an image of a person depicts a "70% attractive person". Also in this fields I would be happy for hints / links.

**Remarks:**

- I don't ask for opinions on whether this makes sense or not.

Comment: See [_Deep Metric Learning Beyond Binary Supervision_](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09626) in CVPR 2019